# How can I get data from a json via GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, graphql, gatsby

```
enter code here {
 "compdata": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "FlexBox",
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Grid layout",
},
```

]
}

```
enter code here **file in:-- src-data-data.json**
enter code here export const IndexQuery = graphql`
query IndexQuery {
dataJson {
compdata {
  id
  example
}
```

}
}
`

> Blockquote giving me error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'compdata')

Comment: Can you please specify your problem more clearly, it is very difficult to know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Often with graphql and react you use a graphql client (maybe [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/)), and that should handle a lot of stuff for you. THough I am not too sure what you are trying to do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to follow the [docs about Sourcing from JSON](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/sourcing-data/sourcing-from-json-or-yaml/).

That said, you don't need to use GraphQL when sourcing from a JSON local file, you can just import the object such as:

```
import React from "react"
import JSONData from "../../content/My-JSON-Content.json"

const SomePage = () => (
  <div style={{ maxWidth: `960px`, margin: `1.45rem` }}>
    <ul>
      {JSONData.compdata.map((data, index) => {
        return <li key={`content_item_${index}`}>{data.title}</li>
      })}
    </ul>
  </div>
)
export default SomePage
```

In this case, you can import your JSON data as `JSONData` and loop it through the array of `compdata`.

However, if you still want to use GraphQL, you will need to use the [`gatsby-transformer-json`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-json/) plugin, what will create a queryable GraphQL node from your JSON source:

Install it by:

```
npm install gatsby-transformer-json
```

And use it your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `./src/your/json/folder`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

The alias of the node will rely on your folder structure and your naming (which hasn't been provided), in the docs example, given a `letters.json` such as:

```
[{ "value": "a" }, { "value": "b" }, { "value": "c" }]
```

So in your GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) you will be able
to query `allLettersJson` node:

```
 {
  allLettersJson {
    edges {
      node {
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can add a `typeName` option to fix your naming such as:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-json`,
  options: {
    typeName: `Json`,
  },
},
```

In that case, the created node will be `allJson`.