# How can I get data from a json via GraphQL and create dynamic pages in gatsby?

Tags: json, graphql, gatsby

its giving me error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'edges') when I deleted edges

```
 from const {compdata} = data.allJson.edges.node;
```

its showing same error for node. What is right way to map this and I have to create dynamic pages using same json file.Please help me for this issue.

**src/data/data.json**

```
{
    "compdata": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "FlexBox",
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Grid layout",
    }]
}
```

**graphQl query**

```
query MyQuery {
    allJson {
        edges {
            node {
                compdata {
                    id
                    example
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-json`,
  options: {
    typeName: `Json`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
    name: `data`
  },
},
```

**this is my index.js**

```
 export default function Home(data) {
 // const { compdata } = data.dataJson
 // console.log(data);
 const {compdata} = data.allJson.edges.node;
 console.log(compdata);
 return (
  <Layout>
     <h1>Home page</h1>
    <h1>{JSONData.title}</h1>
       <ul>
         {compdata.map((data1, index) => {
          return <li key={`content_item_${index}`}>{data1.example}</li>
          })}
       </ul>
 </Layout>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed what I explained in the other answer ([How can I get data from a json via GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103678/how-can-i-get-data-from-a-json-via-graphql)).

- Importing the JSON directly
- Using GraphQL (via `gatsby-transformer-json`)

To create dynamic pages from a JSON (new information), you just need to import the JSON into your `gatsby-node.js` file, since it's there where the dynamic magic happens:

```
const path = require("path")
import JSONData from "../path/to/your/json/file.json"

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const youtTemplateFile= path.resolve(`src/templates/yourTemplate.js`)

  JSONData.compdata.forEach((item) => {
    createPage({
      path: item.title,
      component: youtTemplateFile,
      context: {
         id: item.id,
       },
    })
  })
}
```

In this case, you'll be creating dynamic pages (via `createPage` API) that will use a template (`youtTemplateFile`). In the snippet above I'm looping through your JSON object to create dynamic pages on the fly.

The slug for those pages will be the title since `path: item.title` but you can customize the JSON to add new fields accordingly or treat the title as slug (removing white spaces and lower casing it).

In this case, I'm using the context API to send the `id` that will allow you to create custom filtered queries to get the data from each item (if needed).

The nodes will be created using `gatsby-transformer-json` plugin so there you'll need to use the GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) to test all the queries.

Recommended readings:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/
- https://itnext.io/reading-data-from-a-json-file-with-gatsby-graphql-572b18ab98a

Comment: I'm not able to understand from where you getting the context because i have to make graphql query for this in my template.js and  i'm not able to query this.

Comment: Read the documentation to get the scope of what you are trying to do. You haven't provided enough details to find a copy/paste solution as you are trying to. The context here is what you are passing to the template (not getting, sending). There, depending on your data structure you'll need to filter but, as I said, you'll need to test the query in the `localhost:8000/___graphql`. The idea is to create dynamic pages from a JSON in the `gatsby-node.js` and there send the context to the template to get the specific data for each page. It's impossible to know how your node will be called actually

Comment: I'm done with that thank you for your help :). Actually I'm new in gatsby thats why it's taking time to me.